# convolution of two functions and relations with their p-norms

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $1\leq p< \infty$. Then I have proved the convolution $f\ast g\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $||f\ast g||_p\leq ||f||_p||g||_1$. Does $f\ast g$ continuous?

When $p=\infty$, I have only obtained $f\ast g$ continuous. Do the above results $f\ast g\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ hold for $p=\infty$?

Give a counterexample that $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but $f\ast g\notin L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Also give a counterexample that 
$f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $1\leq p< \infty$, but $f\ast g$ not continuous.

Comment: You won't find a counterexample to $f\in L^\infty,\,g\in L^1,\, f\ast g \in L^\infty$. For $p < \infty$, $f\ast g$ need not be continuous, but it often is.

Comment: why? such counterexample does not exist hence the result holds.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting "Give a counterexample that $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but $f\ast g\notin L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$." I read it as asking for $f\in L^\infty,\,g\in L^1$ such that $f\ast g\notin L^\infty$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do the above results $f*g\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ hold for $p=\infty$?

Yes, $\|f*g\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_1$. Hint: in the convolution integral, estimate $f$ by $\|f\|_\infty$.

Here is an idea for a counterexample to continuity of $f*g$ when $p<\infty$. Let $f(x)=|x|^{-\epsilon}$ near $0$ (you can make $f=0$ outside of some neighborhood of $0$). When $\epsilon$ is small enough, $f\in L^p$. Next, let $g(x)=|x|^{\epsilon-1}$, also defined by $g=0$ away from $0$. Clearly $g\in L^1$. The convolution is unbounded near $0$. Indeed, the integral defining $f*g(0)$ diverges, and for $x$ near $0$, $f*g(x)$ will be large.